# Can't find documentation of @react-native-firebase/admob lib in https://rnfirebase.io/

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-firebase

Did admob disappear from @react-native-firebase lib?
I can't find any sign in its official website https://rnfirebase.io/.

Answer (score 2):

Admob is removed from firebase(Google Firebase team have removed it in upstream level) and
It will never be in **react-native-firebas**e again, It's still available in [V11.5](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/v11.5.0). But you won't get any update for this repo. and this is the doc link of [rnFirbase admob](https://rnfb-docs.netlify.app/admob/usage).  So you have to find alternative for react native library for admob. follow this [link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/5329) to get more information about removal.